# How to select a range from '[' to ':' and replace?

Tags: microsoft-word, find, wildcards, range

I have a document with a many looks like look something like:

```
[9/22/17 10:46 AM] xxxxxxxx: llllllllllllllllllll
[9/22/17 10:46 AM] Cc:  cccccccccc
[9/22/17 10:46 AM] Me: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
[9/22/17 10:46 AM] Ccc: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I am trying to select the range from `[` to `:` and replace it with a blank. I know I have to use wildcards and ignore white space in word but I can't seem to get the range correct. I searched around but can't seem to find exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re confusing yourself my misusing the word “range”. 
`[0-9]` is a range matching every digit (in “Arabic” numerals),
`[aeiou]` is a range matching every vowel. 
Those aren’t what you want.

If you want to match everything through the *last* colon on the line,
that might be tricky. 
But if you are always searching for everything through the *second* colon
(i.e., plowing through the one that’s part of the time), use `\[*:*:`. 
The `\` causes the `[` (i.e., `\[`) to be treated as an ordinary character,
and not the beginning of a range. 
Then match everything (`*`) through a colon,
and then everything through a colon again.

Comment: This did it! thanks for clearing up the misuse of "range"

Answer (score 2):

I realized the reason why `[*:` was not working was because `[` is a wildcard character and I had to put a `\` in front of it.